# Powershell script if and

Tags: powershell

I want to make a script that checks two time if a process is running.
First I would like to check normally if a process is running and second time I want to wait 30  seconds until the next check.

Here I have something like this:

```
$check=Get-Process hl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($check -eq $null) {
Start-Sleep -s 30
}
```

If in both cases the process is not running I want poweshell to send me a mail with this :

```
$EmailFrom = “mail@gmail.com”
$EmailTo = “othermail@yahoo.com”
$Subject = “Process not running”
$Body = “NOT RUNNING”
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“user”, “pass”);
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

It's something with and but I can't figure out how exactly.

So it will be something like this:
if process not running {sleep} and if second time checking not running {mail}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$check1 = -not ( Get-Process hl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
$check2 = -not ( Get-Process hl -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue )

if ($check1 -and $check2) {
    # email
}
```

Normally `Get-Process` returns either process objects, or nothing at all. In terms of truth testing, "one or more anythings" compares as `$true` and "no things" compares as `$false`.

- -not ( get-process ) with a running process, would == $true, this makes it $false.
- -not ( get-process ) with a stopped process, would == $false, this makes it $true.

So the if test is simple - `if ($check1 -and $check2)`  "if this and this evaluate as $true"